# Pythonでエクセルの行をランダムに読み込む方法 TypeError len()

Tags: python, python3

#### やりたいこと

Pythonでエクセルの中にある行数をランダムで１行のみ選んで読み込みたいです。

`random.choices()` を使ってやってみましたが、下記のコードだとこちらlenエラーが表示されます。
lenは使えないと表示されます。
エクセルの複数行の中からランダムで1行のみ選択可能でしょうか。
もし分かる方がいましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

**エラー内容**

```
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

エクセルのデータ

```
content,photo1,photo2,photo3,photo4
test1,1_1.jpg,1-2.jpg,1-3.jpg,1-4.jpg
test2,2-1.jpg,2-2.jpg,2-3.jpg,2-4.jpg
test3,3-1.jpg,3-2.jpg,3-3.jpg,3-4.jpg
```

#### 実現したい結果

エクセルの行数からランダムで１行のみ選択したいです。

例

```
test2,2-1.jpg,2-2.jpg,2-3.jpg,2-4.jpg
```

コード

```
import pandas as pd
import random

excel = r'test.xlsx'

#エクセル読み込み
df = pd.read_excel(excel,dtype=str)

#ランダムで1行のみ読み込み
for index, row in random.choices(df.iterrows()):

 file_names=[row.photo1,
 row.photo2,
 row.photo3,
 row.photo4
 ]
 
 #photo1からphoto4のリスト出力
 print(file_names)

 #content出力
 print(row.content)
```

お手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pandas.DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)を使えば`import random`が不要になって、

> Return a random sample of items from an axis of object.

この行を：

```
for index, row in random.choices(df.iterrows()):
```

このように変更すれば良いでしょう。

```
for index, row in df.sample().iterrows():
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ドキュメントの方確認致しました。ランダムの場合sampleを使うんですね、勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
content,photo1,photo2,photo3,photo4
test1,1_1.jpg,1-2.jpg,1-3.jpg,1-4.jpg
test2,2-1.jpg,2-2.jpg,2-3.jpg,2-4.jpg
test3,3-1.jpg,3-2.jpg,3-3.jpg,3-4.jpg
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))

#
row = df.sample(n=1)
file_names = row.values[0,1:].tolist()

print(file_names)
print(row['content'].values[0])
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法でも問題なくできました。values とtolistの方法も教えてくれてありがとうございます。